# Trigger from GIT to Jenkins buildWithParameters ignores parameter value in pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, githooks

I have a **post-receive** hook in GIT (works ok) which calls

```
http://ip:port/job/project_name/buildWithParameters?token=abc&ABC=qwe
```

**ABC** is my parameter which is defined in Jenkins' project as **String parameter** with default value **xyz**. URL has value **qwe**.

[image]

My Jenkins **pipeline script** is

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                print env.ABC
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the build is triggered from GIT, `env.ABC` prints xyz and not qwe.

[image]

**How to get the value qwe from the URL ?** My goal is to pass versioned tag name from GIT to pipeline.

Thanks

---

**EDIT #1 (suggestion from Matt Schuchard)**

Not working too.

URL from post-receive hook

```
http://ip:port/job/project_name/buildWithParameters?token=abc&ABC=works&DEF=works
```

Parameter defined in Jenkins UI for the project

[image]

Pipeline script

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'DEF', defaultValue: 'failed', description: '')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                print 'by params.ABC -> ' + params.ABC
                print 'by params.DEF -> ' + params.DEF
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

---

**SOLUTION (by Virginie)**

It's necessary to quote & in URL.

```
http://ip:port/job/project_name/buildWithParameters?token=abc\&ABC=works\&DEF=works
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `&` will need to be escaped, or the whole URL quoted, if using a Unix shell script.
Can you try this:

```
http://ip:port/job/project_name/buildWithParameters?token=abc\&ABC=works\&DEF=works
```